# Check unique list identifier from item on click

Tags: java, android, listview, android-studio, onitemclicklistener

guys what's up?
I'm still new to android and creating some testing app.

- I have two Lists in my view. (Left and Right).
- List Filled with values.

I trying to add selected list item value to other lists.
For example, If I clicked on an item in a left list. I wanna add selected item to Right list,

implemented OnItemClickListener into my code and OnItemClickListener onItemClick method is firing for both lists.

Any way to identify clicked list in an onItemClick method?
any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading official API. Found a solution.
We can get the ID on the selected list.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    if(adapterView.getId() == R.id.leftList){
        // It's a left list
    }else{
        // It's a Right list
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, but if you are trying to identify which list was clicked, you can call getId on the view in onItemCLick:

```
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            switch (parent.getId()){
                case R.id.left_list:
                    ...
                    break;
                case R.id.right_list:
                    ...
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Sorry for my bad English. but you understand it as well. I tried this way but it's not working. If I get the id from view parameter. I receive different value.

Comment: I'm sorry, my bad, v is the item itself. use: parent.getId()

Comment: You mean parent by AdapterView right? Yes, it's working. Thanks in advance.